# Find the locus of the foot of perpendiculars drawn from the vertex on a variable tangent to the parabola $y^2=4ax$

Tags: conic-sections

The tangent will be 
$$y=mx+\frac am$$

The line perpendicular to this will be 
$$y=-\frac 1m x$$

Solving these equations 
$$x=-\frac{a}{1+m^2}$$
And $$y=\frac{a}{m(1+m^2)}$$

I am not able to eliminate m to obtain the locus. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac xy=\cdots=-m$$

Replace the value of $m$ in anyone of the last two relations to eliminate the foreign variable $m$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take and eliminate $m$ from them $$x=-\frac{a}{1+m^2}~~~(1), y=\frac{a}{m(1+m^2)}~~~(2)$$ dividing them 
you get $m=-x/y$ put it in (1) to get the required locus as $$x(x^2+y^2)=-ay^2.$$

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $...=-ay^2$?

Comment: @Aditya Oh! yes I have edited it now, thanks.